# Simulate a tcp connection in Go

Tags: networking, tcp, go

In Go, a TCP connection (net.Conn) is a io.ReadWriteCloser. I'd like to test my network code by simulating a TCP connection. There are two requirements that I have:

1. the data to be read is stored in a string
2. whenever data is written, I'd like it to be stored in some kind of buffer which I can access later

Is there a data structure for this, or an easy way to make one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using `bytes.Buffer`? It's an `io.ReadWriter` and has a `String` method to get the stored data. If you need to make it an `io.ReadWriteCloser`, you could define you own type:

```
type CloseableBuffer struct {
    bytes.Buffer
}
```

and define a `Close` method:

```
func (b *CloseableBuffer) Close() error {
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No idea if this existed when the question was asked, but you probably want `net.Pipe()` which provides you with two full duplex `net.Conn` instances which are linked to each other

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: I've rolled this answer into a package which makes things a bit simpler - see here: https://github.com/jordwest/mock-conn

---

While Ivan's solution will work for simple cases, keep in mind that a real TCP connection is actually two buffers, or rather pipes. For example:

```
 Server   |   Client
 ---------+---------
  reads <===  writes
 writes ===>  reads
```

If you use a single buffer that the server both reads from and writes to, you could end up with the server talking to itself.

Here's a solution that allows you to pass a `MockConn` type as a `ReadWriteCloser` to the server. The `Read`, `Write` and `Close` functions simply proxy through to the functions on the server's end of the pipes.

```
type MockConn struct {
    ServerReader *io.PipeReader
    ServerWriter *io.PipeWriter

    ClientReader *io.PipeReader
    ClientWriter *io.PipeWriter
}

func (c MockConn) Close() error {
    if err := c.ServerWriter.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := c.ServerReader.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (c MockConn) Read(data []byte) (n int, err error)  { return c.ServerReader.Read(data) }
func (c MockConn) Write(data []byte) (n int, err error) { return c.ServerWriter.Write(data) }

func NewMockConn() MockConn {
    serverRead, clientWrite := io.Pipe()
    clientRead, serverWrite := io.Pipe()

    return MockConn{
        ServerReader: serverRead,
        ServerWriter: serverWrite,
        ClientReader: clientRead,
        ClientWriter: clientWrite,
    }
}
```

When mocking a 'server' connection, simply pass the MockConn in place of where you would use the `net.Conn` (this obviously implements the `ReadWriteCloser` interface only, you could easily add dummy methods for `LocalAddr()` etc if you need to support the full `net.Conn` interface)

In your tests you can act as the client by reading and writing to the `ClientReader` and `ClientWriter` fields as needed:

```
func TestTalkToServer(t *testing.T) {
    /*
     * Assumes that NewMockConn has already been called and
     * the server is waiting for incoming data
     */

    // Send a message to the server
    fmt.Fprintf(mockConn.ClientWriter, "Hello from client!\n")

    // Wait for the response from the server
    rd := bufio.NewReader(mockConn.ClientReader)
    line, err := rd.ReadString('\n')

    if line != "Hello from server!" {
        t.Errorf("Server response not as expected: %s\n", line)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sort of confused. The code you posted here doesn't seem to match what you put in github.

Answer (score 0):

In majority of the cases you do not need to mock net.Conn.

You only have to mock stuff that will add time to your tests, prevent tests from running in parallel (using shared resources like the hardcoded file name) or can lead to outages (you can potentially exhaust the connection limit or ports but in most of the cases it is not a concern, when you run your tests in isolation).

Not mocking has an advantage of more precise testing of what you want to test with a real thing.

https://www.accenture.com/us-en/blogs/software-engineering-blog/to-mock-or-not-to-mock-is-that-even-a-question

Instead of mocking net.Conn, you can write a mock server, run it in a goroutine in your test and connect to it using real net.Conn

A quick and dirty example:

```
port := someRandomPort()
srv := &http.Server{Addr: port}
go func(msg string) {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", myHandleFUnc)
    srv.ListenAndServe()
}
myTestCodeUsingConn(port)
srv.Shutdown(context.TODO())
```

Comment: A code example would go a long way in assisting OP in understanding how it can work.

Comment: An example and bigger explanation is added