# Proper way to test a connection in go

Tags: unit-testing, go, networking, concurrency, deadlock

I am covering project with tests and for that purpose I need dummy TCP Server, which could accept connection, write/read data to/from it, close it etc... I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976950/simulate-a-tcp-connection-in-go) question on stack overflow, covering mocking connection, but it doesn't cover what I actually need to test.

My idea relies on this [article](https://dev.to/williamhgough/how-to-test-tcpudp-connections-in-go---part-1-3bga) as starting point, but when I started implementing channel to let server write some data to newly opened connection, I got stuck with undebuggable deadlock in writing to channel.

**What I want to achieve** is to write some data to server's channel, say `sendingQueue chan *[]byte`, so later corresponding `[]byte` will be sent to newly established connection.

During these little research I have tried debugging and printing out messages before/after sending data to channel and trying to send / read data from channel in different places of program.

**What I found out**:

1. My idea works if I add data directly in `handleConnection` with

   ```golang
   go func() {
      f := []byte("test.")
      t.sendingQueue <- &f
   }()
   ```
2. My idea doesn't work if I push data to channel from `TestUtils_TestingTCPServer_WritesRequest` in any form, either with `func (t *TCPServer) Put(data *[]byte) (err error)` or directly with:

   ```golang
   go func(queue chan *[]byte, data *[]byte) {
          queue <- data
   }(t.sendingQueue, &payload)
   ```
3. *It doesn't matter if channel is buffered or not.*

So, obviously, there is something wrong either with the way I debug my code (I didn't dive into cli dlv, using just IDE debugger), or something that I completely miss about working with go channels, goroutines or net.Conn module.

For convenience [public gist](https://gist.github.com/Hiyorimi/aed12823807f8aaab46f9ab6eafbfe71) with full code is available. Note — there is `// INIT` part in the `TestUtils_TestingTCPServer_WritesRequest` which is required to run/debug single test. It should be commented out when running `go test` in the directory.

utils.go:

```golang
    // NewServer creates a new Server using given protocol
    // and addr.
    func NewTestingTCPServer(protocol, addr string) (*TCPServer, error) {
        switch strings.ToLower(protocol) {
        case "tcp":
            return &TCPServer{
                addr:         addr,
                sendingQueue: make(chan *[]byte, 10),
            }, nil
        case "udp":
        }
        return nil, errors.New("invalid protocol given")
    }

    // TCPServer holds the structure of our TCP
    // implementation.
    type TCPServer struct {
        addr         string
        server       net.Listener
        sendingQueue chan *[]byte
    }

    func (t *TCPServer) Run() (err error) {}
    func (t *TCPServer) Close() (err error) {}
    func (t *TCPServer) Put(data *[]byte) (err error) {}
    func (t *TCPServer) handleConnection(conn net.Conn){
        // <...>

        // Putting data here successfully sends it via freshly established
        // Connection:

        // go func() {
        //  f := []byte("test.")
        //  t.sendingQueue <- &f
        // }()
        for {
            fmt.Printf("Started for loop\n")
            select {
            case data := <-readerChannel:
                fmt.Printf("Read written data\n")
                writeBuffer.Write(*data)
                writeBuffer.Flush()
            case data := <-t.sendingQueue:
                fmt.Printf("Read pushed data\n")
                writeBuffer.Write(*data)
                writeBuffer.Flush()
            case <-ticker:
                fmt.Printf("Tick\n")
                return
            }
            fmt.Printf("Finished for loop\n")
        }
    }
```

utils_test.go

```golang
    func TestUtils_TestingTCPServer_WritesRequest(t *testing.T) {

        payload := []byte("hello world\n")

        // <...> In gist here is placed INIT piece, which
        // is required to debug single test

        fmt.Printf("Putting payload into queue\n")
        // This doesn't affect channel
        err = utilTestingSrv.Put(&payload)
        assert.Nil(t, err)

        // This doesn't work either
        //go func(queue chan *[]byte, data *[]byte) {
        //       queue <- data
        //}(utilTestingSrv.sendingQueue, &payload)

        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":41123")
        if !assert.Nil(t, err) {
            t.Error("could not connect to server: ", err)
        }
        defer conn.Close()

        out := make([]byte, 1024)
        if _, err := conn.Read(out); assert.Nil(t, err) {
            // Need to remove trailing byte 0xa from bytes array to make sure bytes array are equal.
            if out[len(payload)] == 0xa {
                out[len(payload)] = 0x0
            }
            assert.Equal(t, payload, bytes.Trim(out, "\x00"))
        } else {
            t.Error("could not read from connection")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your #2 solution should work if you make the channel buffered and don't send the data in a separate goroutine. Also should probably connect to the server *before* you write the data.

Comment: I also think so, but it doesn't. And what's the problem in sending data in the goroutine? Channel writing is supposed to be goroutine-safe.

Comment: Because there are no guarantees when the goroutine will start. There is no data race, but there is a logical race.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help, thanks for trying.
I tested with/without goroutine and with/without extra function f.e. just sending data to channel before establishing connection from client in `TestUtils_TestingTCPServer_WritesRequest`.

Comment: Your gist code calls NewTestingTCPServer in TestUtils_TestingTCPServer_WritesRequest() and in init() with the same port, that would lead to stuff not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a help from a colleague and reading the [article](https://medium.com/golangspec/init-functions-in-go-eac191b3860a) on how `init` works, I found a problem.

It was in `init` function, which was recreating extra server, due to using `:=` assignment. I also updated code to make sure server runs before `net.Dial` and `conn.Read`.